# My update queries won't work

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update

I've got a basic registration, login, profile page webpage up and running and have recently begun implementing forgot password functionality.

Everything seems to be running, but my update queries just don't seem to fire.

For example, the code on my forgot password page creates a new reset key if the email address and things match and then emails the code inside a link (i.e www.mydomain.net/forgotpassword.php?key=xxx).

The page tests if a key is present when you land, the code of which is below:

```
include ('database_connection.php');
session_start();
if($_GET['key'])
{
    $key = $_GET['key'];
     $query_check_key = "SELECT * FROM password_reset WHERE Reset_link='$key' AND Expiration>=NOW() AND used=0";
     $result_check_key = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_check_key);
     $result_check_row = $result_check_key->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
     if(!$result_check_key) {
        echo "Error";
     }

      if (mysqli_num_rows($result_check_key) == 1)
      {
         // Update the database to set the "used" field to 1
        $query_link_used = "UPDATE password_reset SET Used=1 WHERE Reset_link='$key'";
        $result_link_used = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_activate_account) ;

        $_SESSION['Memberid'] = $result_check_row['Memberid']; 
        header("Location: reset_password.php");
      }
}
```

The if statement evaluates to true when I try this as the page is redirected to reset_password.php and the session is successfully created correctly. But when I check the database table the Used field has not been updated.

Similarly on the reset_password.php page the update query won't work either:

```
if (empty($error))
        {
            //Query to change password
            $query_change_password = "UPDATE members SET Password=$hashed_password WHERE Memberid=$Memberid";
            $result_change_password = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_change_password);

            if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) > 0)//if update query was successful
            {
                echo '<div class="success">Your password has now been reset. You may now <a href="login.php">Log in</a></div>';

            } else
            {
                echo '<div class="errormsgbox">Oops !Your password could not be reset. Please contact the system administrator.</div>';
            } 
            mysqli_close($dbc);
        }
```

The error array is definitely empty and the if statement checking the affected rows remains at 0 as that statement returns false and falls back to the else statement.

I've run the queries in PHPMyAdmin and they work fine so I cannot see what the issue is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i think you forgot to enclose field value with quots, it suppost to be as '$hashed_password' and well as chk $Memberid

Comment: I'll give that a try, but in the first code block the variables are enclosed with quotes, i.e `"UPDATE password_reset SET Used=1 WHERE Reset_link='$key'"`

Comment: IN your update you run $query_activate_account which i cant see anywhere.

Comment: That solved it! I had copied a bulk of code from another page of mine for various reasons and made changes from there but didn't even spot that error. I'd been wracking my brains for days with that and it was something so small! Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start session in your reset_password.php page and update query string:

```
session_start();
if (empty($error))
{
    $Memberid = $_SESSION['Memberid'];
    //Query to change password
    $query_change_password = "UPDATE members SET Password='$hashed_password' WHERE Memberid='$Memberid'";
```

Comment: Session was already started and so that wasn't an issue. The comment above from @user1844933 about enclosing quotes solved the reset page. However I am still having trouble getting the Used column to update to 1 from the first code block, i.e `"UPDATE password_reset SET Used=1 WHERE Reset_link='$key'"`

Comment: how do you generate your reset key? is it any random value?

Comment: It's a randomly generated hash.

Comment: So is there any possibility of duplication of same value? This is for precautionary measures. There is a error in your query execution. you store the query in $query_link_used variable. but execute as  $result_link_used = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_activate_account); So change it to $result_link_used = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_link_used) ;

Comment: As in the above comments, this has been solved now.Whilst it may be possible, it is incredibly unlikely. I will add in a check for this though a regenerate if it already exists.

Comment: What is your column name **used/Used**? I can see two type of column name in your first two query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84916/discussion-between-chayan-and-james).